# Excel combine IF and SUMPRODUCT formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file which has 3 workbooks

1. List of data of calls happened on any date and its status(Status is set as a dropdown list which is coming from 2nd workbook)
2. As mentioned, it has a simple list if records to create a dropdown list
3. Dates in columns starting from 1DEC till 31DEC. The third sheet has the same list of master list like

```
STATUS                1-Dec        2-Dec    3-Dec    and so on
Send Info & Callback    0            44       47
Call Backs              34           12        0
Voice Mails Left        78           47        1
```

What I am looking is the following:

It should look for any date which is equal to 12/1/2016 (mmddyyyy) format which are in multiple columns like M,R, W and is equal to Send Info & call back which is in workbook1, count the sum of it and  put the total in workbook3 under Dec1 for that particular label as shown above.

Attached screenshot

[Workbook1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb12a.png)
[Workbook3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY7F0.png)

Comment: it would be great if you could post screenshots of the data in the other "Worksheets"

Comment: And also, What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am able to just get the total for any label ir-respective of dates with this formula                                                              `=SUMPRODUCT(('Startups & Emerging Co.'!N3:N126="Send Info & Callback")+('Startups & Emerging Co.'!T3:T126="Send Info & Callback")+('Startups & Emerging Co.'!Y3:Y126="Send Info & Callback"))`

Comment: Can Worksheet 1 col L have the date in each row. that would make it easier

Comment: @nightcrawler23, there would be date in each row in Column L, R & W. Not sure if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

From what i have understood so far, you can use this formula to get the number of specific remarks on specific dates

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$15=G$1)*($C$2:$C$15=$F2))
```

`$A$2:$A$15` refers to the date column (worksheet1 column l in your case)

`G$1` refers to the date you are looking for, (worksheet2 B1/C1/... in your case)

`$C$2:$C$15` refers to the remarks column (worksheet1 column N in your case)

`$F2` refers to the remark you are counting (worksheet2 A2/A3/... in your case)

*see if this fulfills all your requirements*

Comment: The value gives me 0. Here's the exact formula i gave. `=SUMPRODUCT(('Startups & Emerging Co.'!L3:L126="12/1/2106")*('Startups & Emerging Co.'!N3:N126="Send Info & Callback"))`  Also why it is multiplying the first bracket with the 2nd one?

Comment: why are you checking for the year 2106. we just finished the year 2016. :)

Comment: the formula is basically checking multiple conditions. the multiplication ensures you count only those case where both eh criteria are met

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter nightcrawler's formula in curvy brackets {}. You often get 0 as a results if something which should be evaluated with a Matrix formula is evaluated in normal brackets

Comment: That won't work as the function won't accept curly braces.

Comment: Did you enter with them strg+shift +enter ?

Comment: No, would you mind typing the formula here based on what i have written `=SUMPRODUCT(('Startups & Emerging Co.'!L3:L126="12/1/2106")*('Startups & Emerging Co.'!N3:N126="Send Info & Callback"))`

Comment: paste the formula in the repective cell and then do not hit enter, but enter+strg+shift. This will put curly brackets around the formula and thread it as a Matrix formula.

Comment: tried doing so it shows te formula like `{=SUMPRODUCT(('Startups & Emerging Co.'!L3:L126>="12/1/2106") & ('Startups & Emerging Co.'!N3:N126="Send Info & Callback")){` with curly brace at the end and value still 0

Comment: ITry to replace the "&" in the formula  with "*"